# "Package xcolor error" shows up when a child doc has an embedded pdf

Tags: color, lyx, windows

I am working on LyX Version 1.6.9.
While compiling ClassicThesis, I receive the following error message:

```
package xcolor error: undefined color 'Blue'/'Maroon'/'Black' etc
```

This only happens when one of the child documents has a pdf embedded in it (via insert - file - external material). There is no problem viewing pdf of the child document alone (using `pdfview`). Please help.

Comment: Do you supply `svgnames` or `dvipsnames` options to the `xcolor` package somewhere by any chance ?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). If you provide a minimal working example [(MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) others can help you better and faster.

Comment: No, I didn't supply any svgnames or dvipsnames options.

Comment: Thank you.MWE: I have compiled the main document adding one child document at a time. Only when I added the one which contains a pdf, it refused to compile showing the xcolor message.

Comment: @Anna: Without seeing which document class you use and which packages with which options you load we can only guess what is happening. If your pdf file causes the error, I suggest to prepare a MWE that adds the pdf file and build a `zip` file containing both. Give us a link to the `zip` file so we can test it on our computers ...

Comment: Can you please guide me how to prepare a MWE?

Comment: The document class is 'report (KOMA-Script)'. The strangest thing now happened: compilation worked with one of the child docs with pdf, but it completely ignored the other one. And I still did not change a thing...

Comment: This is the latest LaTeX log: ("C:\Documents and Settings\Anna\Local Settings\Temp\lyx_tmpdir.Hp1932\lyx_tmpb
uf0\ClassicThesis_v9.out")
("C:\Documents and Settings\Anna\Local Settings\Temp\lyx_tmpdir.Hp1932\lyx_tmpb
uf0\ClassicThesis_v9.out"
! I can't write on file `ClassicThesis_v9.pdf'.
Please type another file name for output
! Emergency stop.
\Hy@OutlineName ...utline goto name{#2}count#3{#4}
                                                  
l.1 \BOOKMARK [1][-]{Resum\'e.1}{Resum\351}{}
                                             % 1
*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)

Comment: @Anna: You can edit your question; please read the [FAQ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq) and the [About page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: @Anna: This looks like you are either trying to create the included PDF (i.e. the included PDF and your document have the same name) or have the document open in Adobe Reader while TeXing it. If it's the later, use a different PDF viewer.

Comment: @Martin: Thank you very much! Although the names of the pdf and the document were not the same, there was an error in the name of the pdf. After fixing the error, the main document was successfully compiled.