# Package xcolor Error: Undefined colors “Maroon”/“Royal Blue” when master has PDF included classicthesis 3.1

Tags: errors, color, pdf, lyx, classicthesis

I am using `classicthesis` 3.1 in Lyx 2.0.6. When I include PDFs in the master document, I receive the following error:

```
! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `Maroon'.

See the xcolor package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.13 \begingroup \color{Maroon}
                                \spacedallcaps{\myTitle} \endgroup\\
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

This topic has previously been asked and closed, but provided solutions do not work:

- [Error with xcolor package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64298/error-with-xcolor-package)
- ["Package xcolor error" shows up when a child doc has an embedded pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97371/package-xcolor-error-shows-up-when-a-child-doc-has-an-embedded-pdf)

When I include PDFs in the original `classicthesis` template, I can get the document to compile if I do not remove the original `Chapter<1,2,3>.lyx` files. Once changed, the original template does not always compile. `classicthesis.sty` has not been modified as shown below.

```
% Colors
% ********************************************************************
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{xcolor} % [dvipsnames] 
\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55} % chapter numbers will be semi transparent .5 .55 .6 .0
\definecolor{webgreen}{rgb}{0,.5,0}
\definecolor{webbrown}{rgb}{.6,0,0}
%\definecolor{Maroon}{cmyk}{0, 0.87, 0.68, 0.32}
%\definecolor{RoyalBlue}{cmyk}{1, 0.50, 0, 0}
%\definecolor{Black}{cmyk}{0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Uncommenting `\definecolor` for `Maroon`, `RoyalBlue` and `Black` does not resolve the issue.

I have modified `classicthesis-config.tex` to change the text area and added new commands under user ad-hoc commands, but otherwise it is set to default.

Is this a conflict between `xcolor` and `pdfpages`? Or a colorspace issue?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I also encountered this problem and found the following solution.

This problem is caused by the `pdfpages` package that itself load the `xcolor` package with no option, while the problematic colors are defined in the `dvipsnames` option of the `xcolor` package. This 'bug' is described in 'Pitfalls' section of the `pdfpages` manual.

The solution to these, explained in the manual, is to load the `xcolor` package with the `dvipsnames` option before the `pdfpages` package. Which is actually done by `classicthesis.sty`.

The problem is that when you use the Lyx internal PDF include, it load the `pdfpages` package before any user supplied options. So the only workaround is not to use the Lyx PDF include.

Declare the `\usepackage{pdfpages}` in preamble and then include the pdf through the `\includepdf[<key=val>]{<filename>}` in an evil red text in latex.

Comment: The same can happen with `tikz` which apparently also loads `xcolor`.

Answer (score 10):

Another workaround is to add the desired xcolor options in the document class definition

```
\documentclass[...,table,usenames,dvipsnames]{...}
```

Comment: How would the OP do this using LyX?

Comment: @cfr You are right, I failed to find an easy way to do that in LyX!

Answer (score 7):

I also encountered this problem but for me just uncommenting `\definecolor` for Maroon, RoyalBlue and Black resolves the issue.

I'm using `classicthesis` from the italian package of Lorenzo Pantieri.

Comment: I encountered the same problem but using the original classicthesis v4.1. I could, however, solve it as @vale did: by uncommenting `\definecolor` for the three problematic colors in the `classicthesis.sty` file.

Answer (score 2):

This problem recently popped up for me when trying to compile `RMarkdown` code to `beamer` slides. I had two machines with identical setups (OSX version (MacOS High Sierra, version 10.13.6 (17G65)) Rstudio version (1.1.456) R version (3.5.1) (with native pandoc installation) Tex live Distribution (2018)), where one worked perfectly, while the other produced the error:

```
! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `Maroon'.
```

After some helpful comments, I stumbled across the solution for me. I had installed a `homebrew` version of `pandoc` on the computer that was compiling properly, but not on the other. The latest `brew` edition appears to have rectified the problem that was created on the native RStudio version. This may help others who have a similar problem. The brew version can be installed via:

```
$ brew install pandoc
```

Answer (score 1):

In classicthesis move the xcolor definition into the classicthesis-config file before the configuration of pgf/tikz. That should solve it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I'm using the `Arsclassica` [Article LaTeX Template Version 1.1 (1/8/17)](http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com) from Lorenzo Pantieri and Vel. Contrary to @vale's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141736/287683), I don't have any `\definecolor` in my code.

The issue was solved by changing the `RoyalBlue` color to `blue` in the `\hypersetup` options in the `structure.tex`file:

```
\hypersetup{ %draft, % Uncomment to remove all links (useful for printing in black and white)
colorlinks=true, breaklinks=true, bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered,
urlcolor=webbrown, linkcolor=Royalblue, citecolor=webgreen, % Link colors
pdftitle={}, % PDF title
pdfauthor={\textcopyright}, % PDF Author
pdfsubject={}, % PDF Subject
pdfkeywords={}, % PDF Keywords
pdfcreator={pdfLaTeX}, % PDF Creator
pdfproducer={LaTeX with hyperref and ClassicThesis} % PDF producer
}
```