# tikz-Picture in classicthesis-LyX v4.1

Tags: tikz-pgf, lyx, color, classicthesis

I exported a plot from MATLAB using matlab2tikz into a file `testfig.tikz`. As written [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz), I included

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
```

into `classicthesis-config.tex`. When I compile my thesis, I receive an error:

```
Package xcolor Error: Undefinded color 'Maroon'.

\begingroup \color{Maroon}
                  \spacedallcaps{\myTitle} \endgroup
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

Even though the problem seems to be similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124636/package-xcolor-error-undefined-colors-maroon-royal-blue-when-master-has-pdf) one, I could not solve it. I do no include any pdf documents into my thesis.

Additionally, it must be related to `classicthesis` because everything works fine, when I include the same file into a plain `article` document (also using LyX and the built in `Input` functionality as well as the preamble additions from above).

Comment: Have you tried adding `dvipsnames` option to the documentclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both pgfplots and classicthesis load xcolor package, there must be an option clash. Moreover, classicthesis loads it with the dvipsnames option and expects the corresponding set of named colors. 
You could try either loading pgfplots at the very end of classicthesis-config.tex, or using some other named color for the title (`\color{purple}` should always work). Check the documentation for xcolor and pgfplots.

Comment: I moved the three lines I mentioned in my first posting below `\usepackage{classicthesis}` in classicthesis-config.tex and everything works fine. Thanks!